# Naming launch images without using asset catalog

Tags: ios6, ios7, launchimage

I'm working on a Universal app (my first app) that runs on both iOS 6 and 7 and I'm creating my launch images now.

I've read the Apple documentation on this area but I find I'm still confused.

For the moment, I'd like to work out how to create and link up all my launch images without using the Asset Catalog, if possible.

I've got most, but not all, of the launch images created and added into the Launch Images area of my project like so:

```
Portrait Non-Retina (iOS 6.1 and Prior) 768x1004 No image with correct dimensions found
Portrait Retina (iOS 6.1 and Prior) 1536x2008 No image with correct dimensions found
Landscape Non-Retina (iOS 6.1 and Prior) 1024x748 No image with correct dimensions found
Landscape Retina (iOS 6.1 and Prior) 2048x1496 No image with correct dimensions found
Portrait Non-Retina 768x1024 Default-Portrait
Portrait Retina 1536x2048 Default-Portrait@2x
Landscape Non-Retina 1024x768 Default-Landscape
Landscape Retina 2048x1536 Default-Landscape@2x
```

But I'm puzzled as to how to name the iPad image files that are still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to do what you are trying to do by naming alone. If you don't want to use the asset catalog (which totally solves the problem without effort, so why would you not use it????), you will have to set up the Info.plist yourself, as Apple explains [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html):

> In iOS 7, an app can use a different launch image depending on which version of iOS it’s running in. To provide different launch images, add the UILaunchImages key to the Info.plist file and use a dictionary to describe each launch image. To learn more about handling launch images, see “App Launch (Default) Images” in iOS App Programming Guide.

Comment: So, the problem arose when Apple came out with iOS 7 then? So, after that we apparently cannot use the area I am trying to fill in?  I'm just trying to understand here.   I have no particular reason for not using the Asset Catalog other than to learn how things were done the old way before I advanced to the new way.

Comment: Then use the asset catalog, build the app, and look in the built app and see what is done there. What the asset catalog does for you automatically (both with naming and with the _Info.plist_) is exactly what you would have to do if you did it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find the naming conventions in the section called **App Launch (Default) Images** of [Apples documentation for resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html)

Comment: I read it again.  It says, "Other optional modifiers may also be included in the name, and several standard modifiers are discussed in the sections that follow."  So, I resized my Default-Portrait@2x file & renamed it Default-Portrait-20@2x (where -20 is my new optional modifier) & I tried to plug it into the "Portrait-Retina (iOS 6.1 and Prior)" slot.  Xcode replied, "To use 'Default-Portrait-20@2x.png' as a launch image, it must be renamed to 'Default~ipad.png'".  So, I'm still missing something here.  Maybe, I need to leave the name as Default-Portrait@2x and get it from a diff. directory.

Comment: @Gallymon You don't get to make up your own name modifiers.